# Netplan configuration problem for local NAS-Ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: networking, server

I am trying to set up a local read household NAS now, when I am trying to apply the netplan I got plethora of messages, the message for the latest:

```
** (generate:2354): DEBUG: 05:45:34.814: Processing input file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml..
** (generate:2354): DEBUG: 05:45:34.815: starting new processing pass
(generate:2354): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 05:45:34.815: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation local (GLocalVfs) for ?gio-vfs?
/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml:2:1: Error in network definition: unknown key 'version'
version:  2
^
```

the latest version:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
version:  2
renderer:  networkd
ethernets:
 enp4s0:
addresses:  [192.168.1.100/24]
gateway4: 192.168.1.1
nameserver:
 addresses:[4.2.2.2, 8.8.8.8]
```

Please help

Edit: Server version 20.04 and I tried several manuals with similar results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My netplan config looks like this:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
    etc.
```

It seems the first line "network:" has been deleted from your file. I'm pretty certain it will work after that line is added.

After that, your file should look like this (with the same indentation):

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp4s0:
            addresses: [192.168.1.100/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [4.2.2.2, 8.8.8.8]
```

Also note that it should be nameservers, not nameserver (per [examples](https://netplan.io/examples)), and you need spaces after each colon.

Comment: Thank you for your time. After adding the missing part I got a new error message. Error in network definition: expected mapping (check indentation). network:^

Comment: Yes I believe you have to make the correct indentation. See suggestion in my answer.

Comment: EDIT after some tinkering with spaces Invalid YAML: aliases  are not supported.

Comment: Please repost you revised netplan config then - also watch out at the last line "addresses" - there should be space between colon and the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

New netplan, as I have written (please note there are no spaces):

```
network:
version:  2
renderer:  networkd
ethernets:
enp4s0:
addresses:  [192.168.1.100/24]
gateway4: 192.168.1.1
nameservers:
addresses:[4.2.2.2, 8.8.8.8]
```

Comment: How many spaces should I have?

Comment: You need space in last line after colon: `addresses: [4.2.2.2, 8.8.8.8]`

Comment: And indentation as in my example above - please report if that works.

Comment: Worked. Thank you.